# How to clear the std::map<K,V*> container and delete all the pointed objects safely?

Tags: stdmap, c++98

None of the standard library containers will call `delete` on contained raw pointers. I have checked for a solution on `SO` for `C++98` but have not found the answer.

I have created `template <typename K, typename V> void clearAndDestroy( std::map<K, V*> *&myMap)` as a replacement function for `std::clear()` (remove all elements and call the destructors).

It works for maps with pointers to objects `std::map(key,V*)`. The function works also for cases when map contains same V* pointers for the different keys.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

// clearAndDestroy deletes all objects and remove them from the std::map(K,V*) container.
template <typename K, typename V>
void clearAndDestroy( std::map<K, V*> *&myMap)
{
    if(myMap == NULL)
        return;

    std::set<V*> mySet;

    typename std::map<K,V*>::iterator itr;
    typename std::set<V*>::iterator sitr;

    itr = myMap->begin();
    while (itr != myMap->end()) {
        mySet.insert(itr->second);
        ++itr;
    }

    sitr = mySet.begin();
    while (sitr != mySet.end()) {
        delete(*sitr);
        ++sitr;
    }

    myMap->clear();
}

template <typename K, typename V> void clear1( std::map<K, V*> *myMap)
{
    if(myMap == NULL) return;
    typename std::map<K, V*>::iterator itr = myMap->begin();

    while (itr != myMap->end()) {
        typename std::map<K, V*>::iterator toErase = itr;
        ++itr;
        myMap->erase(toErase);
        delete(toErase->second);
    }
}

template <typename M> void clear2( M *myMap )
{
    if(myMap == NULL) return;

    for ( typename M::iterator it = myMap->begin(); it != myMap->end(); ++it ) {
        delete it->second;
    }
    myMap->clear();
}

class MY_CLASS
{
public:
    int counter;
    string *message;

    MY_CLASS(int c, string *m):counter(c), message(m) {
        std::cout << "Constructor MY_CLASS " << this << std::endl;
    };
    ~MY_CLASS()
    {
        if(message) {
            cout << "Being destroyed MY_CLASS: " << *message << " this = " << this <<endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Being destoyed MY_CLASS: " << " this = " << this <<endl;
        }

        if(message) {
            delete message;
            message = NULL;
        }
    }

    MY_CLASS(const MY_CLASS & other)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy Constructor MY_CLASS " << this << std::endl;
        //1.
        counter = other.counter;
        //2.
        if(other.message) {
            message  = new string;
            *message = *other.message; // copy the value
        }
        else {
            message = NULL;
        }
    }
};

void print(const string *str,MY_CLASS *& value, void *)
{
    if (value && value->message)
        cout << value->counter << " ! " << *(value->message) << endl;
}

int main() {

    std::map<std::string, MY_CLASS *> *mpa = new std::map<std::string, MY_CLASS *>;
    MY_CLASS *p = new MY_CLASS(2, new string("abc"));

    mpa->insert(std::pair<std::string, MY_CLASS *>("1", p));
    mpa->insert(std::pair<std::string, MY_CLASS *>("2", p));

    clearAndDestroy(mpa);
    delete mpa;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Constructor MY_CLASS 0x111ccb0                                                                                                                 
Being destroyed MY_CLASS: abc this = 0x111ccb0
```

Being restricted to C++98 is `clearAndDestroy` my best option? Thank you!

Comment: This is a temporary message regarding your [this close-vote-review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/19293756). This is a typo question, please be more careful next time.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you can take is using an object wrapper. Place the pointer you want within an object and have the destructor call the delete on the pointer. Basically building a simple "smart-pointer".

```
class AutoDeletePtr {
    MY_CLASS* pointer;
    AutoDeletePtr(MY_CLASS* myObjectPtr) {pointer = myObjectPtr};
    ~AutoDeletePtr() {delete(pointer)};
}
```

You can insert these objects into the std::map.